# See what would be merged in one git command?

Tags: git, merge

Currently, before merging a branch, I use the following commands to see what changes will be merged:

```
base=$(git merge-base other HEAD)
git diff $base other
```

Is there a single git command to achieve this?

Regards,
Jochen

Comment: As Sven says, there is a way - though in general, even if there's not, you could elide your temporary variable and wrap the whole thing up in an alias.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I preview a merge in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817579/how-can-i-preview-a-merge-in-git)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git diff ...other
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: the question "[How can I preview a merge in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817579/how-can-i-preview-a-merge-in-git)" does mention the context of seeing what would be merged when fetching:

```
[alias]
    # fetch and show what would be merged (use option "-p" to see patch)
    incoming = "!git remote update -p; git log ..@{u}"
```

With:

> - "`git incoming`" to show a lot of changes, or
> - "`git incoming -p`" to show the patch (i.e., the "diff"),
> - "`git incoming --pretty=oneline`", for a terse summary, etc

You can find more elaborate scripts in this:

- [GitHub example](https://github.com/ddollar/git-utils/blob/master/git-incoming):
- [gitpastiche](https://bitbucket.org/ssaasen/git-pastiche/src/38949c010f42/bin/git-incoming?at=master)