# How do you preview merge changes in one git command?

Tags: git

["git diff master...topic"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817579/how-can-i-preview-a-merge-in-git) is not it.

If master has been merged into topic after branching "git diff master...topic" will show changes that are already in master.

What you want is the equivalent of the following:

git merge topic --no-commit
git diff --staged
git merge --abort

Comment: Did you mean `What *I* want is the equivalent of the following` ?

Comment: What about `git diff master topic`?

Comment: Perhaps you need to start by defining what you mean by "merge changes"... All changes that will be introduced by the merge might be something like `git diff $(git merge-base master topic) topic`... Of course that doesn't cover any conflicts that might occur, but it does represent all the changes that `git merge` will *attempt* to make...

Comment: `git diff $(git merge-base master topic) topic` is equivalent to `git diff master...topic` and I already explained why it's inadequate

Answer (score 3):

You can write a bash script with those commands in it.

```
#!/bin/sh

git merge topic --no-commit
git diff --staged
git merge --abort
```

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure if there is a got command or not, if you find out let me know