# Equivalent of 'arc diff --preview' for Git?

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

In Phabricator/Arcanist, there is a command `arc diff --preview` which lets you see all your code changes in a nice UI before you send it off to code review (see
 https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_diff/ for more details).

What's the equivalent to this in Git?

Comment: That would likely be a pull request on a git hosting service like github. Otherwise you’ll be looking for something using `git diff`

Comment: Is there a way to preview what the pull request would look like without actually pushing my local branch to remote?

Comment: I only know of using the terminal commands. As for a “nice UI” I have no clue.

Comment: You probably want `git diff mybranch origin/master` (there are many git UIs, I'm sure most of them will have an equivalent for this).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I preview a merge in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817579/how-can-i-preview-a-merge-in-git)

Comment: This is the feature I missed the most when I switch from Phabricator to Github

Answer (score 0):

I recently migrated a massive mono-repo from Phabricator to Github and sadly there is no equivalent to `arc diff --preview` for Github. The best equivalent I've found to share your changes without actually creating a pull request / submitting your code for review is to create a new remote branch, push your changes there and share the link to your commit on the remote branch.

Say you're on master, this can be a simple flow

```
git checkout -b dev--preview

# make your changes on this branch
git add . && git commit -m "Previewing changes" && git push -u origin dev--preview

# copy the last commit id
git rev-parse HEAD | pbcopy
```

Your shareable link is going to be of this format

```
https://www.github.com/<org-name>/<repo-name>/commit/<your commit SHA from your clipboard>
```