# Keep the .env file in production server on git deploy

Tags: git, github, cloudways

In my Git repository, for security reasons, I do not have the .env file; however, in the production environment, this file already exists at the root and is configured (and it's not versioned). My goal is that when I deploy to Cloudways, this production file is retained, and I don't have to reconfigure it again with each deployment.

However, when I perform the pull via Cloudways, this production file gets deleted. How can I prevent Git from deleting it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Git pull from deleting local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55324083/how-to-prevent-git-pull-from-deleting-local-files)

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, I prefer to keep the "to be retained" files in a different folder - and as part of your deployment process, you can create symbolic links once the code has been deployed into appropriate folders. For eg (concept-wise), this is how capistrano manages different releases.

```
<app installation folder>
 |
 |- release1 # date + time-stamped folder names
 |- release2
 |- .
 |- .
 |- .
 |- current # symbolic link to the appropriate release folder
     |- configFile # symlink from ../shared/<file>
 |- shared # folder where the common files can live irrespective of which is the current release
```

In the above example, your file (that should not change across releases) can go into the `shared` folder.