# How to preview changes before git pull

Tags: git, github, git-fetch

I want to check the changes that will done to the files after I run git pull. I know we use `git fetch` to retrieve new objects from remote repository without changing local repository.
But how can I view these changes in editor ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817579/how-can-i-preview-a-merge-in-git/5818279. You just want to know what will happen if you merge. That is easy to find out and has been well covered before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I preview a merge in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817579/how-can-i-preview-a-merge-in-git)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that all your local modifications are commited, one way would be to do:

```
git fetch origin

# To see local changes as the "new" version
git diff origin/yourbranch HEAD

# Or to see remote changes as the "new" version
git diff HEAD origin/yourbranch
```

This will compare your local repository (currently `HEAD`) with the remote content `origin/yourbranch`.

Comment: Probably want to swap the two arguments, so that things in HEAD but missing from `origin/yourbranch` show up as additions, not deletions.

Comment: @chepner Hmmm, based on the wording of the question which is "what will be done", perhaps the original order may be preferred? Imagine a fast forward only pull where some files will be added and some files will be deleted.

Comment: Right as well. In doubt I've edited with both possibilities.

Comment: I would do: `git diff HEAD...origin/yourbranch` or `git difftool -D HEAD...origin/yourbranch` or `git log HEAD...origin/yourbranch`.

Comment: If you have not committed your files yet, `git fetch` followed by just `git diff origin/yourbranch` will work too.

Answer (score 4):

> to check the changes that will done to the files after I run `git pull`

Then the simplest solution is just run it and look! First, work out where you are:

```
% git show --oneline --no-patch
bf1908d ...
```

Now pull, and then diff to see what you just did:

```
% git pull
% git diff bf1908d
```

This shows you exactly what you are asking for: the changes done to the files after running `git pull`.

If you like the changes, do nothing. If you don't, and wish you had never done this pull, then `git reset --hard bf1908d` and you're right back where you were before the pull, no harm done.

Comment: *Absolutely* this. `git rev-parse @` is a shorter, more direct version of the `git show --oneline --no-patch`, but you don't even need to do that. `git pull; git diff @{1}` and if you don't like what you see `git reset --hard @{1}`

Comment: Clever. Yes, I always forget about `@{1}` as "where I just was".

Comment: I'm not one for using git pull at all in the first place, but I still like this idea, it's simple and effective. Warning: don't do this if your sandbox has uncommitted local changes, the `git reset --hard @{1}` will destroy them. Mind you, it's best practice to commit or stash your local changes before you pull anyway, but Git does not require it, so I think it's worth a caveat.

Answer (score 1):

Once you're done `git fetch`, you have a full local database of all the changes on the remote, which you have just fetched, so you have all to powers of Git to explore those changes.

- `git log origin/branch` will show you the list of commits
- `git log -p origin/branch` will show the commits with their changes, by commit.
- `git diff origin/branch` or `git diff HEAD origin/branch` (see @Gaël J's answer)

If your local changes are committed, you can also check out `origin/branch` to play with it before going back to your own branch.

```
git checkout origin/branch  # go to the fetched state from origin
# explore stuff
git checkout branch  # go back to your own branch
```